# How to handle empty response in Swift 5 Result

Tags: swift

I have a view controller and a custom class to call APIs. One API doesn't return anything if it succeeds. I get empty response.

```
class APIManager {
    static func callAPI(completion: @escaping ((Result</*Empty*/, Error>))) {
        completion(.failure(Error()))
        if statusCode == 200 {
            completion(.success(/*Pass nothing*/))
        }
    }
}
```

I know I can use `String` type and pass `String` literal. Is there any better way?

Comment: You could mark the success parameter as optional and pass nil.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I thought this. But Kamran's answer is better

Comment: Ok, I misread the question and thought there were other cases when you did want to return something but if not then I agree that Void is better.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `Void` as below,

```
static func callAPI(completion: @escaping (Result<Void, Error>) -> Void) {
     if statusCode == 200 {
          completion(.success(()))
     }
}
```